# Google Sheets Go to Today button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with horizontal dates (starting at 1 January, ending in 31 Dec).
I'm trying to put a button in the sheet which will make it jump to "Today".

This is what I have so far:

```
function goToSheet(sheetName, row, col) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, col)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}

function goToSheet2b() {
  goToSheet("2016", 1,299);
}
```

2016 is the sheet name, 299 is the column number for today's date and it actually jumps to today, but I would need to manually change 299 in order for it to work every day.  Is there a simple way of going about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933878/open-google-spreadsheet-at-date/

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to attach the button to the following "goToTodayKeepRow" function:

```
function goToTodayKeepRow() {
  var ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var as = ass.getActiveSheet();
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  var datesRange = as.getRange(1, 1, 1, as.getLastColumn());

  for (var column = 1; column <= datesRange.getNumColumns(); column++) {
    var cell = datesRange.getCell(1, column);
    if (isValidDate(cell.getValue()) && cell.getValue().getTime() === today.getTime()) {
      as.getRange(as.getActiveCell().getRow(), cell.getColumn()).activate();
      break;
    }
  }
}
function isValidDate(d) {
  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]" )
    return false;
  return !isNaN(d.getTime());
}
```

The advantages are:

- cells which don't contain a valid date are skipped, it uses the isValidDate function from this post: [Run custom function if value in cell is date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347237/run-custom-function-if-value-in-cell-is-date)
- the function keeps the active row, it only changes the active column, if that is not desired the line before break can be replaced with "cell.activate();"
- the date compare is done with getTime() function

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching this script to your button:

```
function activateToday() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lc = s.getLastColumn();
  var range = s.getRange(1, 1,1,lc).getValues();
   for(var i=0;i<range[0].length;i++){
    if(range[0][i].getDate()+ range[0][i].getMonth()+1 ==new  Date().getDate()+new Date().getMonth()+1 ){
     s.getRange(1,i+1).activate();
      break;
    }}}
```